# Как создать кнопку "Откликнуться через LinkedIn

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin

Добрый день. На  [это странице](http://wargaming.com/ru/careers/html5-banner-animator/) на вакансию можно откликнуться через LinkedIn. Как это сделано? Может есть готовое решение от LinkedIn ?

Comment: готового не нашел, но есть API https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api

Comment: Как я вижу, на сайте wargaming идет запрос данных без последующей авторизации. Тем самым можно подтянуть поля имя, фамилия, должность и ссылку на профиль.

Но это несовсем правильно. Я думал, есть возможность некого готового решения, а не костылей.